# Convert an existing Replica Set In Mongodb to a Sharded Cluster

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have a replica set with 3 nodes. Is there a way to convert this existing Replica Set to a Sharded Cluster. Please find below the config file of the replica set:
[image]

All of my 3 nodes in replica set have sharding enabled:-

```
sharding:
  clusterRole: shardsvr
```

Comment: According to the screenshot all the services are running on one host only, not 3

Comment: If clusterRole is shardsvr then you have already setup a shaded cluster, what do you want? Did you configure a Config Server?

Comment: This is documentation on [Convert a Replica Set to a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/).

Answer (score 3):

sharding is enabled at the database level ....and then implemented at the collection level.   any operating replica set can work in a sharding environment but there wouldn't be a compelling reason to do sharding until you have multiple replica clusters working in parallel...  it's a big decision - no going back...and you need to be very clear on your sharding key....  so definitely invest time in learning the technology at the MongoDB University.